# Getting error when building the opencv.sln from cmake with msvc2012

Tags: opencv

i am trying to install opencv with opencv_contrib 
i downloaded opencv and opencv_contrib from GitHub of the same branch (3.4) 
i built the opencv and opencv_contrib with cmake, and evrey thing worked fine. but when i try to build the Opencv.sln i am  getting  errors and not all the modules are built ( i need the opencv_tracking module)
here are the errors i am getting:

```
enter Error 437 error C2039: 'isfinite' : is not a member of 'std'  

C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\tracking\src\trackerCSRTUtils.cpp   150 1   opencv_tracking
Error   46  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'    C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   409 1   quirc
Error   50  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'    C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   615 1   quirc
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   22  1   quirc
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   39  1   quirc
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   49  1   quirc
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   59  1   quirc
Error   7   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   69  1   quirc
Error   8   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   79  1   quirc
Error   9   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   89  1   quirc
Error   10  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   99  1   quirc
Error   11  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   109 1   quirc
Error   12  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   119 1   quirc
Error   13  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   129 1   quirc
Error   14  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   139 1   quirc
Error   15  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   149 1   quirc
Error   16  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   159 1   quirc
Error   17  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   169 1   quirc
Error   18  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   179 1   quirc
Error   19  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   189 1   quirc
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   199 1   quirc
Error   21  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   209 1   quirc
Error   22  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   219 1   quirc
Error   23  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   229 1   quirc
Error   24  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   239 1   quirc
Error   25  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   249 1   quirc
Error   26  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   259 1   quirc
Error   27  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   269 1   quirc
Error   28  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   279 1   quirc
Error   29  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   289 1   quirc
Error   30  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   299 1   quirc
Error   31  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   309 1   quirc
Error   32  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   319 1   quirc
Error   33  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   329 1   quirc
Error   34  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   339 1   quirc
Error   35  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   349 1   quirc
Error   36  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   359 1   quirc
Error   37  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   369 1   quirc
Error   38  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   379 1   quirc
Error   39  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   389 1   quirc
Error   40  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   399 1   quirc
Error   41  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   409 1   quirc
Error   42  error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   419 1   quirc
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '.' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   21  1   quirc
Error   44  error C2059: syntax error : '.' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   45  1   quirc
Error   45  error C2059: syntax error : '.' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   121 1   quirc
Error   67  error C2059: syntax error : '[' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    124 1   quirc
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : '}' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   29  1   quirc
Error   43  error C2059: syntax error : '}' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\version_db.c   430 1   quirc
Error   407 error C2065: 'HUGE_VALF' : undeclared identifier    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\aruco\src\apriltag_quad_thresh.cpp  390 1   opencv_aruco
Error   408 error C2065: 'HUGE_VALF' : undeclared identifier    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\aruco\src\apriltag_quad_thresh.cpp  445 1   opencv_aruco
Error   405 error C2065: 'INFINITY' : undeclared identifier C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\aruco\src\zmaxheap.cpp  177 1   opencv_aruco
Error   406 error C2065: 'INFINITY' : undeclared identifier C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\aruco\src\zmaxheap.cpp  178 1   opencv_aruco
Error   62  error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    75  1   quirc
Error   65  error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    82  1   quirc
Error   59  error C2065: 'newdim' : undeclared identifier   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    74  1   quirc
Error   64  error C2065: 'newdim' : undeclared identifier   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    75  1   quirc
Error   66  error C2065: 'newdim' : undeclared identifier   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    86  1   quirc
Error   56  error C2065: 'olddim' : undeclared identifier   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    73  1   quirc
Error   63  error C2065: 'olddim' : undeclared identifier   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    75  1   quirc
Error   51  error C2085: 'bits_remaining' : not in formal parameter list    C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   616 1   quirc
Error   47  error C2085: 'grid_bit' : not in formal parameter list  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   410 1   quirc
Error   48  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   410 1   quirc
Error   52  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\decode.c   616 1   quirc
Error   61  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'min' C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    75  1   quirc
Error   58  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'newdim'  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    74  1   quirc
Error   55  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'olddim'  C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    73  1   quirc
Error   54  error C2275: 'size_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    73  1   quirc
Error   57  error C2275: 'size_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    74  1   quirc
Error   60  error C2275: 'size_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression   C:\opencv-3.4\3rdparty\quirc\src\quirc.c    75  1   quirc
Error   200 error C2784: 'void cv::dnn::NMSFast_(const std::vector<_Tp> &,const std::vector<_Ty> &,const float,const float,const float,const int,std::vector<int> &,float (__cdecl *)(const BoxType &,const BoxType &))' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Tp> &' from 'const std::vector<_Ty>'  C:\opencv-3.4\modules\dnn\src\nms.cpp   31  1   opencv_dnn
Error   202 error C2784: 'void cv::dnn::NMSFast_(const std::vector<_Tp> &,const std::vector<_Ty> &,const float,const float,const float,const int,std::vector<int> &,float (__cdecl *)(const BoxType &,const BoxType &))' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Tp> &' from 'const std::vector<_Ty>'  C:\opencv-3.4\modules\dnn\src\nms.cpp   40  1   opencv_dnn
Error   199 error C2896: 'void cv::dnn::NMSFast_(const std::vector<_Tp> &,const std::vector<_Ty> &,const float,const float,const float,const int,std::vector<int> &,float (__cdecl *)(const BoxType &,const BoxType &))' : cannot use function template 'float cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v9::rectOverlap(const T &,const T &)' as a function argument    C:\opencv-3.4\modules\dnn\src\nms.cpp   31  1   opencv_dnn
Error   201 error C2896: 'void cv::dnn::NMSFast_(const std::vector<_Tp> &,const std::vector<_Ty> &,const float,const float,const float,const int,std::vector<int> &,float (__cdecl *)(const BoxType &,const BoxType &))' : cannot use function template 'float cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v9::rectOverlap(const T &,const T &)' as a function argument    C:\opencv-3.4\modules\dnn\src\nms.cpp   40  1   opencv_dnn
Error   439 error C3861: 'acosh': identifier not found  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\tracking\src\trackerCSRTUtils.cpp   163 1   opencv_tracking
Error   440 error C3861: 'acosh': identifier not found  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\tracking\src\trackerCSRTUtils.cpp   173 1   opencv_tracking
Error   438 error C3861: 'isfinite': identifier not found   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\tracking\src\trackerCSRTUtils.cpp   150 1   opencv_tracking
Error   458 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xobjdetect343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\xobjdetect\tools\waldboost_detector\LINK opencv_waldboost_detector
Error   370 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\3rdparty\lib\Debug\quircd.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\objdetect\LINK   opencv_objdetect
Error   442 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_aruco343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\aruco\LINK   opencv_test_aruco
Error   460 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_aruco343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\apps\interactive-calibration\LINK    opencv_interactive-calibration
Error   223 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_dnn343d.lib'    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\dnn_objdetect\LINK   opencv_dnn_objdetect
Error   244 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_dnn343d.lib'    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\text\LINK    opencv_text
Error   396 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_dnn343d.lib'    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\dnn\LINK opencv_perf_dnn
Error   443 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_dnn343d.lib'    C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\dnn\LINK opencv_test_dnn
Error   444 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_face343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\face\LINK    opencv_test_face
Error   409 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\face\LINK    opencv_face
Error   431 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\xobjdetect\LINK  opencv_xobjdetect
Error   436 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\objdetect\LINK   opencv_perf_objdetect
Error   445 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\objdetect\LINK   opencv_test_objdetect
Error   448 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\apps\traincascade\LINK   opencv_traincascade
Error   453 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\apps\createsamples\LINK  opencv_createsamples
Error   459 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect343d.lib'  C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\dpm\LINK opencv_dpm
Error   361 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_text343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\datasets\LINK    opencv_datasets
Error   446 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_text343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\text\LINK    opencv_test_text
Error   441 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_tracking343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\tracking\LINK    opencv_perf_tracking
Error   447 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_tracking343d.lib'   C:\opencv-3.4\opencv-3.4-build\modules\tracking\LINK    opencv_test_tracking
Error   461 error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  134 5   INSTALL
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i surpassed the errors by using a previous version (3.4.0)
to retain: never use the latest version.